# Android Textview text not centered

Tags: android, textview, position, center

I'm having issues with centering text in a textview.
The problem is, in the layout manager in eclipse/android studio everything works fine and the text is centered nicely, but on my physical device it appears to be positioned too low. Here are two screeenshots of the layout manager of the IDE and my mobile phone(HTC One X), I'm speaking of the time and score in the gray areas:

**My physical device:**

[image]

**Layout Manager of IDE:**

[image]

Here's the layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gameActivityBackGroundColor"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/scoreText"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreView"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/timeviewbackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/startscore"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/timeText"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/timeviewbackground"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="00:24"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Level 2"
    android:textColor="@color/levelTextColor"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set "includeFontPadding" property of TextView to false.

Comment: Awesome .. the only answer that works. Thanks a lot.